# Double #s when defining a new command that uses \mint instead of using \mint directly

Tags: minted, parameters

Why does `\dollarcom` give a different result than `\mint{bash}|$#|`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\dollarcom}{\mint{bash}/$#/}

\begin{document}

\dollarcom
\mint{bash}|$#|
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Reading from the `pdflatex` output it seems like `$#` is taken as an illegal parameter number. In this case, how can I define a command with the same output of `\mint{bash}|$#|`?

Note: I absolutely do *not* want to use `\mint{bash}|$#|` in my text because the non-escaped `$` breaks code highlighting in Kile and after that half of my LaTeX source looks green as if in math mode.

**Update:**

I found a hack to make Kile recognize a command as a `\verb` command.
If you want to change the system's syntax highlightining open `/usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax/latex.xml`, if you want to add syntax highlighting only for your user open `~/.kde/share/apps/katepart/syntax/latex.xml`.
If the latter does not exist create the missing directories and copy the system-wide file into it.

Now modify the chosen file.
In particular there is a section that looks like this:

```
  <!-- LaTeX command in text mode -->
  <context name="ContrSeq" attribute="Keyword" lineEndContext="#pop">
    <StringDetect String="verb*" attribute="Keyword" context="Verb"/>
    <RegExpr String="(Verb|verb|lstinline)(?=[^a-zA-Z])" attribute="Keyword" context="Verb"/>
    <DetectChar char="&#xd7;" attribute="Bullet" context="#stay"/>
    <RegExpr String="[a-zA-Z@]+(\+?|\*{0,3})" attribute="Keyword" context="#pop"/>
    <RegExpr String="[^a-zA-Z]" attribute="Keyword" context="#pop" />
  </context>
  <context name="ToEndOfLine" attribute="Normal Text" lineEndContext="#pop">
  </context>
```

Modify the line `<RegExpr String="(Verb...` to:

```
<RegExpr String="(Verb|verb|lstinline|mint|mint\{[a-zA-Z0-9=, ]+\})(?=[^a-zA-Z])" attribute="Keyword" context="Verb"/>
```

This will allow kile to highlight `\mint|text|` or `\mint{some,options}|text|`
in the correct way.

To make Kile highlight also the `minted` environments check for the section that looks like:

```
  <!-- filter the environment name and check the type -->
  <context name="BeginEnvironment" attribute="Environment" lineEndContext="#stay">
    <RegExpr String="(lstlisting|(B|L)?Verbatim)" attribute="Environment" context="VerbatimEnvParam"/>
    <RegExpr String="(verbatim|boxedverbatim)" attribute="Environment" context="VerbatimEnv"/>
```

And change the last line to:

```
    <RegExpr String="(verbatim|boxedverbatim|minted)" attribute="Environment" context="VerbatimEnv"/>
```

Look for the section:

```
  <!-- parse verbatim text -->
  <context name="Verbatim" attribute="Verbatim" lineEndContext="#stay">
    <DetectChar char="&#xd7;" attribute="Bullet" context="#stay"/>
    <RegExpr String="\\end(?=\s*\{(verbatim|lstlisting|boxedverbatim|(B|L)?Verbatim)\*?\})" attribute="Structure"  context="VerbFindEnd"/>
  </context>
```

And change the `RegExpr` line with:

```
    <RegExpr String="\\end(?=\s*\{(verbatim|lstlisting|boxedverbatim|minted|(B|L)?Verbatim)\*?\})" attribute="Structure"  context="VerbFindEnd"/>
```

Look for the section:

```
  <!-- end of verbatim environment -->
  <context name="VerbFindEnd" attribute="Normal Text" lineEndContext="#pop" fallthrough="true" fallthroughContext="#pop">
    <RegExpr String="\s*\{" attribute="Normal Text" context="#stay"/>
    <RegExpr String="(verbatim|lstlisting|boxedverbatim|(B|L)?Verbatim)\*?" attribute="Environment" context="#stay"/>
    <DetectChar char="}" attribute="Normal Text" context="#pop#pop#pop#pop#pop" endRegion="block"/>
  </context>
```

And Change the second `RegExpr` line to:

```
    <RegExpr String="(verbatim|lstlisting|boxedverbatim|minted|(B|L)?Verbatim)\*?" attribute="Environment" context="#stay"/>
```

After that Kile should correctly highlight the `minted` environments.

I think there should be a way to add at least user-specific syntaxes, if not for each file, but I cannot find any `syntax` directory in `~/.kde/*`.

Unfortunately this does not highlight "shortcuts", so you either have to add all of them manually, or you must use ``minted` with all the options every time.

Comment: Regarding your syntax problems: Does using `\mint{bash}|$#|%$` help? I've seen some syntax highlighting restored by using the complementary symbol in comments.

Comment: @Werner No it does not work. Kile ignors the dollar after the `%`(correctly).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to define `\dollarcom` with a "stringified `#`":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\edef\dollarcom{\noexpand\mint{bash}/$\string#/}

\begin{document}

\dollarcom

\mint{bash}|$#|

\end{document}
```

[image]